# How to make a TextBox listen to INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I googled for hours, but did not find a solution I was able to understand (I'm very new to OOP and C#...).

The task at hand is this:

- I have a class "DutyDay" which has the property "ActualShowTime" which is a DateTime object.
- a TextBox named "textBoxLegalFDP".
- a method "CalculateLegalFDP" in which the "ActualShowTime" will be taken trough a series of calculations based on various other variables.

Now, whenever the "ActualShowTime" property in the class "DutyDay" has been changed, the TextBox "textBoxLegalFDP" should listen to that change, take the updated value of "ActualShowTime", send it trough "CalculateLegalFDP" and then put the new calculated result in the "textBoxLegalFDP.Text" property to be shown in the TextBox.

This is what I've done so far:

```
namespace DutyTimeRechner
{
public class DutyDay : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DateTime _actualShowTime;
    public DateTime ActualShowTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _actualShowTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!_actualShowTime.Equals(value))
            {
                _actualShowTime = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ActualShowTime"));
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

I hope this was correct so far, according to what I found on the internet.

I did'nt include the methode "CalculateLegalFDP" since it is not of the essence here.

What kind of code do I have to write, to make the TextBox listen to the change of the property and hand it to "CalculateLegalFDP" and the update it's own "Text" property?

I was thinking about something simple like:

```
textBoxLegalFDP.AddHandler.OnPropertyChanged = PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, "ActualShowTime");
```

But already by looking at it myself I know its crap, and Visual Studio was even less happy with that approach, but just so you know what kind of solution I have in mind!

PS: Does my thinking actually make sense? Or is there a better way to solve all of this?

Edit: here's the XAML code, after I put the DataContext in it (only the relevan parts):

```
<Window x:Class="DutyTimeRechner.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DutyTimeRechner"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Tour Details" Height="450" Width="1000" ResizeMode="NoResize">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:DutyDay x:Key="DutyTimeRechner" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource DutyTimeRechner}" Orientation="Horizontal">
```

and:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxActualFDP" Text="{Binding ActualShowTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="2" Height="26" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="50" Width="43"/>
```

But it didn't work, it just gives me the standard date value "01.01.0001 12:00:00 AM" in the Textbox, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post xaml code?

Comment: Your problem is most likely that you forgot to set the `DataContext` of your page to an instance of `DutyDay`, then WPF/UWP would know to automatically subscribe to the property changed event.

Comment: As a note, `else { return; }` is entirely redundant. You should remove it.

Comment: Is the question about WPF or WinForms? If it's WPF (or UWP) the TextBox would not "automatically subscribe to the property changed event", but a Binding (applied to the Text property) would do.

Comment: @NicoRiff: I'll do that as soon as I can.

Comment: @Clemens I'ts about WPF, and yes, your right of course about the 'else {return}' I will remove it, thanks.

Comment: Simply binding the TextBox in XAML as Pawel wrote, didn't work. So I will try to set the `DataContext` as you guys mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a **`ValueConverter`**

What you need to do is bind your TextBox to the value as you have done

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ActualShowTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"...
```

But us a `ValueConverter` to change the value that is displayed. It would look something like this:

```
public class CalculateLegalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // convert the value in your viewmodel for display
        return CalculateLegalFDP(value);
    }
......
```

Then wire up this converter to your binding:

1) add as a resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:CalculateLegalConverter x:Key="LegalConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

2) Add is to your binding expression:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ActualShowTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource LegalConverter}}"...
```

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for your input, I'll try that out whit the new approach of my programm, I'm sure it will come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

Read about WPF MVVM :).

To solve your problem you need to add binding to your text box control

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ActualShowTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

But since type you are trying to bind with text box is a datetime, you probably need to write converter to convert datetime to string and string to datetime

Comment: In order to make this work, you also have to assign an instance of the DutyDay class to the DataContext of the TextBox or one of its parent elements, preferrably the MainWindow.

Comment: Yes, but since he used INotifyPropertychanged i have assumed that he might know about this:).

Comment: He did obviously not know anything about data binding.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I was reading into the MVVM concept, realizing that I basically put the cart before the horse. So I will start again from scratch, cause I want to learn it right. But the inputs for the `DataContext` and the `DataBinding` will definately helpful further down the road. Thanks :-)

Comment: Good movent :), it was really pure madness, doing anything with no fundamentals:) Good luck :)